# Best way to insert bulk data from one db to other

Tags: java, sql, database, api, jdbc

I have db1 on one server and another db2 on different server. I need to transfer huge amount of data at some conditions.
I have been using batch jobs till now, I was thinking to use Insert into... Select * from... Where condition ="meets" ;
Is there a better or faster way available

Comment: `LOAD DATA INFILE` is hard to beat.

Comment: Will it be faster than insert into select*?

Comment: One way to find out: Benchmark it.